# How to scrape a container in website with varying content?

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to scrap ethis website.
https://www.dhgate.com/wholesale/electronics-robots/c103032.html

I have built a scrapy code:

```
import scrapy
from urllib.parse import urljoin



class DhgateSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'dhgate'
    allowed_domains = ['dhgate.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.dhgate.com/wholesale/electronics-robots/c103032.html']

    
    def parse(self, response):
        Product = response.xpath('//*[@class="pro-title"]/a/@title').extract()
        Price = response.xpath('//*[@class="price"]/span/text()').extract()
        Customer_review = response.xpath('//*[@class="reviewnum"]/span/text()').extract()
        Seller = response.xpath('//*[@class="seller"]/a/text()').extract()
        Feedback = response.xpath('//*[@class="feedback"]/span/text()').extract()

        for item in zip(Product,Price,Customer_review,Seller,Feedback):
            scraped_info = {
                'Product':item[0],
                'Price': item[1],
                'Customer_review':item[2],
                'Seller':item[2],
                'Feedback':item[3],

            }
            yield scraped_info
        next_page_url = response.xpath('//*[@class="next"]/@href').extract_first()
        if next_page_url:
            next_page_url = urljoin('https:',next_page_url)
            yield scrapy.Request(url = next_page_url, callback = self.parse)
```

The problem is that not every container has the customer review or feedback item. So, it only scrapes those which has the complete Product, price, customer_review, seller and feedback items. I want to scrape all the container and where ever there is no customer_review, i want to add a null value. How do i do that? Thanks.

Comment: I feel like you are missing Customer_review in zip().

Comment: sorry that was a typo. That doesnot solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `zip`:

```
def parse(self, response):

    for product_node in response.xpath('//div[@id="proList"]/div[contains(@class, "listitem")]'):
        Product = product_node.xpath('.//*[@class="pro-title"]/a/@title').extract_first()
        Price = product_node.xpath('.//*[@class="price"]/span/text()').extract_first()
        Customer_review = product_node.xpath('.//*[@class="reviewnum"]/span/text()').extract_first()
        Seller = product_node.xpath('.//*[@class="seller"]/a/text()').extract_first()
        Feedback = product_node.xpath('.//*[@class="feedback"]/span/text()').extract_first()

        scraped_info = {
                'Product':Product,
                'Price': Price,
                'Customer_review':Customer_review,
                'Seller':Seller,
                'Feedback':Feedback,
        }
        yield scraped_info

    next_page_url = response.xpath('//*[@class="next"]/@href').extract_first()
    if next_page_url:
        next_page_url = urljoin('https:',next_page_url)
        yield scrapy.Request(url = next_page_url, callback = self.parse)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But what if I don't want those which doesnot have price? How do i do that.

Comment: @UchihaAJ `if Price is not None:` => save item